# Angular http://localhost/BTSWEBVCCAdmin3.0/api/v1/ViewTicketPhotos/GetPhotos?iInstanceID=6992609 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, http, .net-core, service, http-status-code-404

i am getting an HTTP failure response, i can't see why because the api is working, i've checked on swagger/ curl, and its not my first service all the others are working fine

angular service:

```
export class TicketPhotosService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



getTicketPhotos(iInstanceID: string): Observable<TicketPhoto[]> {
return this.http.get<TicketPhoto[]>(`${environment.url}api/v1/ViewTicketPhotos/GetPhotos`,
 { withCredentials: true, responseType: 'json',
 params: {
  iInstanceID
 }})
 .pipe(
  catchError((err, caught) => {
    throw ErrorResponseUtil.build(err);
  })
);
}
```

Conrtoller:

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ViewTicketPhotosConrtoller : BTSWebVCCAdminBaseController
{

    IBALVccDefinitions _balVccDefinition;
    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public ViewTicketPhotosConrtoller(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, ISetting setting, ISecurity security, ILogging logging, IBal bal, IBalEmployee balEmployee, IBALVccDefinitions balVccDefinition, IWeb web, IDotNet dotNet, IDistributedCache distributedCache, ICache cache, IText text, IViewRender viewRenderService, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment) 
        : base(contextAccessor, setting, security, logging, bal, balEmployee, web, dotNet, distributedCache, cache, text, viewRenderService, hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _balVccDefinition = balVccDefinition;
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }




    [HttpGet("GetPhotos")]
    [BTSFilter(useMaintenanceFilter: true, useAuthentificationFilter: true, useCultureFilter: true, useLogAccessFilter: true, useSessionExpiredFilter: true, usePermissionApplicationFilter: false, usePermissionOptionFilter: true)]
    [EnableCors]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string iInstanceID)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(GetImagePath(_balVccDefinition.GetImagesByQuestionnaireInstanceID(iInstanceID)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = Logging.LogErrorWeb(ex, HttpContext);
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new { error, message = "" });
        }
    }
```

image fom curl[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

In your Swagger request you have `.../ViewTicketPhotosConrtoller/...` and the Angular service is just `.../ViewTicketPhotos/...`

Answer (score 0):

its actually the name Controller i've wrote it wrong :( thank you –